# iOS landscape positioning problems Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, landscape, cgpoint

For some reason, I am unable to position a node at the top or bottom of my screen. I used to be able to do this just fine using self.frame.height / 2 but now that I am working in landscape, this line of code is not working.
Notes: my anchor point is 0.5, 0.5 and my scale mode is .aspectFill
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has something to do with the aspect ratio of your scene and using .aspectFill.

When you use .aspectFill, SpriteKit will resize the scene to fill the viewport from edge to edge, both horizontally and vertically, but it won't stretch it.  That means that for a landscape orientation, you will probably end up "cropping" off the top and the bottom of the scene unless you have a particularly shallow scene designed.

In other words, you're encountering the opposite of letterboxing.  The width and height of the scene are fixed, and when the device size differs from that in aspect ratio, it "overflows" one axis offscreen.  In your case, it's probably overflowing the scene off the top and the bottom in order to fill your scene left and right.

There are a few strategies to fix this.

First, you could choose a different scaleMode.  .aspectFit, for instance, would probably return your height calculations to what you expected, but it will come at the cost of also including letterboxing on the left and right, which is probably not what you want, but maybe.

Second, you could compute a new scene size to match the aspect ratio of your viewport.  This will give you the behavior you expect in both directions, but it will also mean that your scene varies in aspect ratio based on the device it is played back on, which will require you to adjust your gameplay and scene layout to accommodate this variable shape.  This is a lot of work, but it is typically the best solution.  (One solution is to resize the scene, but then leave your "real scene" centered in the middle of it, but that can be unsatisfying and problematic for some game types.)

Third, you could use the scaleMode that simply scales the scene to the viewport.  This will cause some squishing/stretching depending on the device, so it is generally not a great option, but depending on the game type you are making, this might be an option.

Comment: thank you so much. I have been looking for this answer for days.